# Cookies in .NET Compact Framework - manual workarounds and cookiecontainer comparision

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

While developing a WMS application for Windows CE I've encountered a problem with lack of cookies support in .NET Compact Framework. Doing my research I've found those two workarounds for the problem:

- [Alex Feinman approach](http://www.alexfeinman.com/download.asp?doc=SessionAwareWebSvc.zip)
- [yoniathome approach](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34d88228-0b68-4fda-a8cd-58efe6b47958/no-cookies-sessionstate-in-compact-framework?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs)

The thing is: my boss insists that I decompile the .NET 4.5 libraries, take the CookieContainer and it's associated classes and reimplement those for the Compact Framework.

The workarounds I've found both base on a simple concept of catching the cookies contained in the `http header` then storing them in a `string` and later sending them back to the server, all using the `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` overrides.

The CookieContainer is a lot more complex than this.

Question is: what could I gain going with the decompile-and-reimplement CookieContainer approach and is it really worth it?